# Alias python to python3 in /bin/sh

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ubuntu

**Context**

I'm using a package involving makefiles. Those makefiles send python commands to the terminal via `/bin/sh` (`SHELL = /bin/sh` in `Makefile.common`), the commands are always `python some_script.py ...`. So for the sake of this question, let's assume I have to stick to `/bin/sh`.

**The issue**

`python-is-python3` is installed:

```
axel@axel-ThinkPad-X250:~$ sudo apt install python-is-python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python-is-python3 is already the newest version (3.9.2-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

`python` is an alias for `python3` in `~/.bash_aliases` as well as in `~/.profile` (`alias python='python3'`) and is functional in `/bin/bash`:

```
axel@axel-ThinkPad-X250:~$ /bin/bash
axel@axel-ThinkPad-X250:~$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
axel@axel-ThinkPad-X250:~$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

But not in `/bin/sh`:

```
axel@axel-ThinkPad-X250:~$ /bin/sh
$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
$ python
/bin/sh: 2: python: not found
$
```

How can I get /bin/sh to understand that python is python3?

Comment: A naive question: couldn't you modify your makefiles to replace `python` with `python3`?

Comment: @Grobu Yes, and it works perfectly but I'd like to avoid doing so. Since I'm cloning the project, I'd have to modify them again manually at every fetch&pull.

Comment: All right. Since `sh` reports that `python` cannot be found in the default PATH, it probably means that there is no `/usr/bin/python` on your system. You could try symlinking `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: Or, if all your `make ...` are to be executed as a regular (non-root) user, you could try prepending `~/bin` to your PATH in `~/.profile` and do the symlinking there (i.e. `~/bin/python` --> `/usr/bin/python3`)

Comment: Yes !! Symlinking `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3` solved my problem. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` did the job, thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't use aliases to solve path problems, and don't litter your file system with hand-made links that aren't managed by your local package manager. Execute the Makefile in a virtual environment where `python` refers to the necessary version of Python.